# Crash after start 3d party app, after that app has crashed

Tags: java, android

In my application, I start others apps on device, like this:

```
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (LaunchIntent == null) return;
    LaunchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    LaunchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

And all work fine, till executed app could crash. In this case, my app force close too.

```
01-06 20:13:00.796    4560-4560/com.example.android.trivialdrivesample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.trivialdrivesample/com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Please change the sample's package name! See README.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Please change the sample's package name! See README.
        at com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:146)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        ... 11 more
01-06 20:13:00.804    1386-1520/?                              W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.example.android.trivialdrivesample/.MainActivity
01-06 20:13:00.804    1386-1520/?                              W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.digitalmediarevolutions.kfmobiledesktop/.activities.MainActivity
```

What should I do to prevent force close of my app?

Comment: From the logcat: `Please change the sample's package name! See README.`

Comment: It is related to another app, not for my

Answer (score 4):

> New Project
>
> To add the In-app Billing Version 3 library to your new In-app Billing project:
>
> Copy the TrivialDrive sample files into your Android project.
>   Modify the package name in the files you copied to use the package name for your project. In Eclipse, you can use this shortcut: right-click the package name, then select Refactor > Rename.

If you want to use the `trivialdrivesample` sample, you have to change the package name. The snippet above from [the developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#AddLibrary) says so, and your logcat says the same thing.

Editing out references to `trivialdrive` from the logcat doesn't make sense, by the way. If you are going to post a logcat, don't edit it into something else.

**Update**

Ok, I see what you're asking better now. I think the problem may be with the way you're setting the action/flags/etc on the intent. I don't see anything obviously wrong, but the method `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`([source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#100)) sets this stuff up for you, so you don't have to. Does the same thing still happen if you remove the `addCategory()`, `setAction()`, and `setFlags()` calls? If you still want the `ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` flag, you can add that in with `addFlags()`, but I'd try it without it first.

It's strange, though. `ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is supposed to prevent this kind of thing from happening.

Comment: I don't want to deal with trivialdrivesample, it is just app which crashes on start. I need to know why my app that runs trivialdrive forse finishes too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Your app is calling trivialdrive(whether on its own or through another package). trivialdrive cannot be run with its default package name. That's what's causing the crash. Either don't run it, or change its package name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You right. However what's happens. My app does launcher functionality, and should to start apps which installed on user device. I use for test device with trivialdrive app. So this situation can happens with any incorrect apps installed on device. And question is why my app finishes if started 3rd part app crashes whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is on 13' but to continue with the answer is to delete this code on your MainActivity

```
  if (base64EncodedPublicKey.contains("CONSTRUCT_YOUR")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please put your app's public key in MainActivity.java. See README.");
    }
    if (getPackageName().startsWith("com.example")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please change the sample's package name! See README.");
    }
```

Regards,

Comment: This is just a remove your error but if i want to add the Key then i want to implement this code :)

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here much later, and for people wanting to use a different package in general (I got this problem also with the Google Trivial sample project).

Have you renamed the applicationID inside the Gradle.build file to your package name?

Tips if above doesnt work: in Android Studio => just use edit-> find in path -> package name to change (remains of package exists somewhere in your project and you will locate where so you can change it).

PS
Tech Lutiers solution for Trivial example work for run on local device, but com.example is not allowed in Google Play Console, so better do it right.